# Resolving promise inside function causes a X(...) is not a function error

Tags: javascript, promise, settimeout

I'm working on load testing my API, but at some point I make a call to a different API. 
Since I don't want to stress the second one, whenever I'm load testing I want to set a timeout and return an OK response like this:

```
function sendMessage(requestLib, blockApi, logger) {
    if(!blockApi){
        return (*my params*) => requestLib(`someURL`, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
            method: 'post',
            data
        });
    }else{
        logger.info("About to use the promise");
        const response = returnOk.then(function() {
            return new Response(200, {}, null, 'dummy.com');
        });
        return response;
    }
}
```

returnOk is a Promise I defined earlier this way:

```
const returnOk = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( function() {
      resolve("Success!") 
    }, 2000) 
  });
```

And the function `sendMessage` is called inside a different function like this:

```
module.exports = ({ requestLib, Logger }) => async function(req, res) {
     // Some unrelated code to decide if I'll call sendMessage
     const response = await sendMessage(requestLib, blockApi, logger)(params);
     // I log the response
     res.end();
}
```

The regular flow works like a charm, but when I'm load testing and I get to returnOk.then()...
It throws

> sendMessage(...) is not a function

If I remove the timeout and just return

```
return new Response(200, {}, null, 'dummy.com');
```

Things work just fine.

Comment: may be "logger.info is not a function"

Comment: where is `sendMessage` defined? Do you need to import `logger` as it works here https://jsbin.com/tilufebibu/4/edit?js,console?

Comment: logger.info works fine, I can see "About to use the promise" in the console.

That first part is the definition of `sendMessage`. It's called inside another function like this:

const response = await sendMessage(requestLib, blockApi, logger)(params);

Comment: We need more detail in order to know what's going on here, in particular about where the call is made. I am suspicious there might be another (non-function) variable called `sendMessage` in the local scope of the call site.

Comment: Adding the code surrounding the call to the main question.

Comment: might be better if you posted the full code. At the moment what you provided works as shown in the jsbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, your `sendMessage(…)` function returns another function:

```
return (*my params*) => …
```

You will need to do the same when mocking `sendMessage`:

```
function sendMessage(requestLib, blockApi, logger) {
    if (!blockApi) {
        return (*my params*) => requestLib(`someURL`, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
            method: 'post',
            data
        });
    } else {
        return (*my params*) => {
            const returnOk = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(resolve, 2000) 
            });
            logger.info("About to use the promise");
            return returnOk.then(function() {
                return new Response(200, {}, null, 'dummy.com');
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Btw, you really shouldn't have this boolean `blockApi` parameter to `sendMessage`. Write two distinct functions with the same signature, and use dependency injection in the code that is calling it.